# Aggregate function in having clause

Tags: sql

I have the following query started below. The goal being to determine the number of partial pallets shipped from a warehouse. Partial pallets are identified by looking at the `log.tran_qty` of a pallet (hu_id) and matching that against the `uom.std_hand_qty`. If that does not match then it is a partial pallet. I can get this query to work properly if I add `hu_id` to the SELECT clause, but if I do that the data set is very large. Is there anyway for me to get a `SUM(log._tran_qty)` by `log.hu_id` without having to add the `hu_id` to the select clause? Hopefully that makes sense...

```
SELECT log.end_tran_date, COUNT(DISTINCT(hu_id)) as 'Pallets'
FROM t_tran_log log    
LEFT JOIN t_item_uom uom ON log.item_number = uom.item_number 
                        and uom.wh_id=log.wh_id
WHERE log.wh_id = 'LANDAIR_C2' 
  and SUBSTRING(log.item_number,6,1) <> 'P' 
  and tran_type='341' and uom.uom = 'CA' 
GROUP BY log.end_tran_date
HAVING SUM(log.tran_qty) <> AVG(uom.std_hand_qty)
ORDER BY log.end_tran_date
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all really help.

Comment: Please review the information about providing a [mre].